# Xerces "fixed" element attribute in XML Schema

Tags: java, xsd, xerces

I have an XML schema element defined as follows:

```
<xsd:element name="Test">
   <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="ElementFixed" fixed="SomeFixedValue"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

As I understand it, "ElementFixed" is a wildcard element. (Since no type is defined, it has the type of "anyType".)

Now maybe this is related or unrelated (to the element being a wildcard), but I am trying to extract the "fixed" value "SomeFixedValue" using the Xerces libraries, and am struggling to work out how to do this. I suspect it may have something to do with XSAttributeUse or XSAttributeDeclaration, but I have not been able to work out what methods I need to call on what objects to extact this information. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work it out. Turns out I needed to call getConstraintType() on the XSElementDeclaration, which returns either XSConstants.VC_NONE, VC_DEFAULT, or VC_FIXED. Then, if the Constraint Type is *not* none, the value is accessed by calling getValueConstraintValue().getActualValue(). For example:

```
short vcKind = xsElementDecl.getConstraintType();
System.out.println("Constraint Type: " + vcKind);
if (vcKind != XSConstants.VC_NONE) {
   System.out.println("Value: " + xsElementDecl.getValueConstraintValue().getActualValue());
}
```